# boostrap datetimepicker change direction

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

Im using bootstrap datetimepicker, need to change the position from top to bottom. any clue ?

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('.form_date').datetimepicker({
            format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
            userCurrent:false,
            pickerPosition: "bottom-left"
        });
    });
</script>
```

how to change the datepicker position to bottom ? that is i want to open the calendar as bottom always...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Bootstrap 3 Datepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/). It has widgetPositioning which define the calendar position when it is opened. Example here:

```js
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
      format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
      widgetPositioning: { horizontal: 'left', vertical: 'bottom'}
    });
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript"  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use the *Modified Version of Bootstrap DateTime Picker*:

***Features:***

1. Support Auto Postion. **Option:** `direction: auto|up|down`.
2. New **Option:** `useCurrent: true|false` *(If no value)*
3. New **Option:** `showToday: true|false`
4. Auto Showing when click on any elements.
5. Auto `set Date/Time view` when value changed in input.

---

in your case you can add driection option `direction: "down"` :

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('.form_date').datetimepicker({
        direction: "down",
        format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
        userCurrent:false,
    });
});
</script>
```

See [**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Shady_Alset/ezba7vur/) example. *I hope it works for you, Thanks !*